# Multicast File copy with Unicast responses

Tags: file-transfer, multicast, satellite

I'm trying to do some multicast big file copies over to remote clients on the other side of a satellite link. The idea is to minimize the amount of traffic going up to the satellite.

I tried using [uftp](http://uftp-multicast.sourceforge.net) without luck. The problem is that, even though we can reach clients via multicast from our central Hub, they aren't able to respond to a multicast address (it's not supported by the return link). As uftp needs to respond to a multicast address in order to report any missing packets I'm out of luck.

So does anyone have any recommendations or alternatives I can use to do the trasfers? Any tip or pointer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A UFTP client sends packets unicast back to the server's IP address.  The fact that the incoming packets are sent to a multicast address shouldn't change that.  If you can't send unicast from the clients back to the server, perhaps you can set up routes on the client side so that the return traffic takes a route other than satellite.

If there's no way at all for the receivers to talk to the sender, you'll need something that supports FEC like [NORM](http://cs.itd.nrl.navy.mil/work/norm/).  Of course, in a situation like this you can't know conclusively that the files arrived successfully.